# How can I create an array of array in cocos2d?

Tags: android, eclipse, cocos2d-iphone

How can I create an array of this type? (all data obtained from the PLIST file)
The name and price, I write to a file manually.

```
 id1: 
       Image1.png: 
           CGRect: Rect
           Name: Name1
           Price: 123
 id2: 
       Image2.png: 
           CGRect: Rect
           Name: Name2
           Price: 456
```

Comment: looks more like array of objects to me????

Comment: sorry for answer, didn't notice an android tag. for this case, i think you can use some standart parser of xml to parse your plist and create your array by yourself.

Comment: In fact, this is an array of objects, but this array of objects containing another array of objects.

Comment: Maybe there is some other way to solve this problem.
In general, there are a lot of sprites, which is called Plist img1 img2 ... imgN, which have default settings, frame, offset, sourceColorRect ... etc. I want to be able to distinguish between these objects not only as img1 ... imgN, but also on the parameters I have added the name and price and when touched screen that object is removed from the array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you want to do but as per my understanding you can do this job easily by creating an array that will keep objects of your custom class which is a subclass of CCSprite. In this custom class you can define all these properties and assign them when getting values from pList. And you can distinguish these objects by any property. 
Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thank you. I realized it's with this method. [link](https://github.com/ZhouWeikuan/cocos2d/issues/15)